# Terminology question: what does a natural isomorphism do to maps?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Suppose I have categories $C$ and $D$ and naturally isomorphic functors $F,G\colon C \to D$. (I do. Trust me.) Now name the natural isomorphism $\theta$; then for any arrow $f\colon x \to y$ in $C$, there are isomorphisms $\theta_x\colon F(x) \to G(x)$ and $\theta_y\colon F(y) \to G(y)$ such that
$$F(f) = \theta_y^{-1} \circ G(f) \circ \theta_x.$$

Morally, $\theta$ "takes $F(f)$ to $G(f)$."

> I want to be able to say "$F(f)$ is naturally isomorphic to $G(f)$." But I think that phrasing is not kosher. The briefest coherent way I think to phrase this relationship is that "$F(f)$ and $G(f)$ are conjugate through natural isomorphisms." But that sentence is a stylistic monstrosity. So ...
>
> **What does one say?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the maps are naturally equivalent.  You're right that saying naturally isomorphic is kinda abusing the terminology but it doesn't sound monstrous to me.  Whatever you choose you should just make sure to explain it the first time you use it.

Answer (score 2):

It is *no* abuse of notation to say that $F(f)$ and $G(f)$ are isomorphic:

$F(f)$ is isomorphic to $G(f)$ in the [arrow category](http://ncatlab.org:8080/nlab/show/arrow+category) of $D$.

Comment: It *is* if you do not specify the category in which that takees place; there are other categories of arrows where the maps are not isomorphic. That there is a category in which what one says becomes correct does not help with messy writing.

Comment: It is no abuse of notation to say that two groups are isomorphic (this refers to the category of groups), but it is a abuse of notation to say that two arrows are isomorphic (this refers to the category of arrows)?

Comment: Well, there is a standard default meaning for the category of groups (which ideally people learn long before even hearing about categories) but you had to link to a Wikipedia page to make clear what caregory of arrows you had in mind. You will not be surprised to learn that quite a lot of people will not be aware of its existance, I guess.

Comment: As you know, Martin, context, context, context.

Comment: Ok. What other categories of arrows are there (where every arrow is an object)? The Wikipedia link was to ensure that the readers who are not familiar yet with that category can simply look it up.

Comment: You can take the discrete category of all arrows, or the category in which morphisms are just squares with isomorphisms, or that in which maps are restriction and correstriction to subobjects —I've seen the last two used. But that is not my pointc the fact that there are many categories of arrows is irrelevant. That there exists a way to disambiguate an ambiguous statement does not, by itself, remove the ambiguity: you *have* to make it explicit.

Comment: If you could have written «It is not an abuse of notation (of language, better) if you préalablement make it clear that you are viewing arrows as objects of such and such category, which is something frequently done.» Abuses of notation or of language occur only in relation to the notational and language conventions established in the context they occur.